# How to use mathjax with vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mathjax

My package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "mathjax": "^2.7.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-moment": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
```

I have a component:

```
<template>
  <div class="post--body" v-html="previewText" id="post--body"></div>
</template>

<script>

import MathJax from 'mathjax'

export default {
  name: 'blog-post',
  data () {
    return {
      post: {body: ""}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch("/api/post/" + this.$route.params.id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.post = data;
        })
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      console.log("tick")
      MathJax.Hub.Typeset()   
    })
  },
  computed: {
    previewText () {
      return this.post.body
    } 
  }
}
</script>
```

But I got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" on MathMenu.js?V=2.7.2:1
How to properly use mathjax?

Comment: You import `MathJax` but try to use `mathjax`.

Comment: give me an example please

Comment: The imported variable name is `MathJax` but you are referecing it as `mathjax` which is different. Try doing `MathJax.Hub.Typeset()`

Comment: I updated my code, but anyway I got error but another one

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can import `mathjax`, because if I console log imported mathjax , it shows empty object. I have gone through the folder directory also that doesn't seem importable. So you need to manually put the `script` src pointing to Mathjax.js

The way I currently use Mathjax in vue is by making a custom global component.

```
<template>
  <span ref="mathJaxEl" v-html="data" class="e-mathjax"></span>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
  export default{
  props:['data'],
  watch:{
    'window.MathJax'(val){
        this.renderMathJax()
    },
    'data'(val){
        this.renderMathJax()
    }
   },
  mounted(){
    this.renderMathJax()
  },
  methods:{
    renderMathJax(){
        if(window.MathJax){
window.MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", window.MathJax.Hub,this.$refs.mathJaxEl]);
    }
  }
}
}
</script>
```

It can be made a bit better by using a variable to save boolean whether, mathjax has been rendered or not, as rendering gets called for two watch values, which both may get triggered in case of browser refresh.

Answer (score 1):

So for MathJax v3, just add the following to your vue component

```
mounted(){
    MathJax.typeset();
},
```

Now when navigating to pages via Vue router the math will render on component mount.